# How do I find gems which offer similar functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is there a way to find say all performance specific gems (e.g. [bullet](https://rubygems.org/gems/bullet) and few others which I am not aware of) via rubygems.org? I guess am looking for gems which are tagged by a keyword (say performance)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) is your friend and gives you what you want.